# How to unlock new weapons in Viktor?

Tags: viktor

After completing a level in the game Viktor (by Shorebound Studios), I noticed on the upgrade screen that there are more available weapons in the game than the starting pistols. How do I unlock those?

I couldn't really find any information on the internet. I've completed another level, but it seems it's not enough to unlock anything.